# What should be the Rest URL for the action "Move the competitor from team1 to to team2"

Tags: rest

I am looking for a good URL, following REST principes, to "Move the competitor from team1 to to team2

My first guess is :

```
/teams/{oldTeamId}/{newTeamId}/competitors/{competitorId}/move
```

But it doesn't look much like REST.

Should I break it into 2 basics calls ?

- Remove competitor from team1,
- Add competitor to team2,

Should I remove some data from URL and pass it into the body ?

I don't really know what to do for this one.

Comment: REST doesn't care how you define your URI as clients should not rely on parsing or interpreting it. Instead you should define and use meaningful link relation names, content negotiation and standardized document formats to exchange messages. This basically allows the server to change and evolve without negatively affecting clients. If you don't need such properties, don't aim for REST to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you would implement this API as a web site.

You would probably have a link to a form -- it might be a form where the competitor, old team, and new team are all blank, or it might be a form where the competitor and old team are pre-populated.  Your consumer updates the default information in the form as required, and submits it.

Notice the first point (raised by Roman Vottner as well) -- your consumer doesn't need to look at the URL at all.  The client knows the HTML form processing rules, so it can create the correct HTTP request without knowing anything about the domain.

The second point is that, since the client is just submitting the form to wherever the HTML tells it to, you can make that anything you want.

One of the interesting properties of HTTP is cache invalidation.  See [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4), any non error response to an unsafe request will invalidate all cached representations of one resource.

So you can choose which resource gets invalidated by specifying its URI as the target of the form.  In effect, it gives you a mechanism for ensuring that a consumer can read its own writes.

So some reasonable choices for the target might be

```
/teams/{oldTeamId}
```

if the team roster is the most important thing.  Or

```
/competitors/{competitorId}
```

if the resource that describes the player is what is most important.

> I don't really know what to do for this one.

Concentrate on make it easy to use.  Your resource model is not your domain model is not your data model.

It will likely be useful to watch Jim Webber's talk [REST: DDD In the Large](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) to get clearer insights into what your "REST" API should really look like.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions, I would not break it into two calls, I would however take some data from that (GET) url and put it in the body of your request. The request would probably be a POST or PUT (or maybe even patch), but definitely not a GET since something is actually changing.

As for a solution, how about a POST request to a /transfer. After all you are (could be) creating a new transfer which takes for example the player, their new team and maybe their old team.

Answer (score 0):

I would use URL to identify the resource which in this case seems to be a competitor's team.

So would

- Make the url as `/competitors/{competitorId}/teams`
- Make the call `PUT`
- Have a body with newTeamId and if required the oldTeamId.